# Using custom markers instead of default marker (Openlayers)

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

This is a simple problem but I'm tangled up in the code and can't figure out the solution; hope someone can help!

I have three markers on a map and want each marker to be a different icon.

I can't work out where to make this happen - do I need to redraw?

I have seen this question [OpenLayers problem with marker icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785915/openlayers-problem-with-marker-icons?rq=1) , but don't understand how to implement the solution.

My code:

```
      function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
    var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.Stamen("toner-background");
    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
    var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(30,55.515).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
    var zoom           = 4; 

    map.addLayer(mapnik);
    map.setCenter(position, zoom );


var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(markers);

var icon1 = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png', size, offset);
var icon2 = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker-gold.png', size, offset);
var icon3 = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker-green.png', size, offset);

        var lonLat1 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(0.1062,51.5171).transform(
                        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                        map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                        );


        var lonLat2 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(2.3470,48.8742).transform(
                        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                        map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                        );

                        var lonLat3 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(7.2692,43.7028).transform(
                        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                        map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                        );

var marker1 = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat1);
    var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
    marker1.icon.size = size;
marker1.icon.offset = offset;

var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(markers, lonLat1);
feature.closeBox = true;
feature.popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.AnchoredBubble, { autoSize: true });
feature.data.popupContentHTML = '<p>Marker1<p>';
feature.data.overflow = "hidden";

marker1.feature = feature;


var markerClick = function (evt) {
    if (this.popup == null) {
        this.popup = this.createPopup(this.closeBox);
        map.addPopup(this.popup);
        this.popup.show();
    } else {
        this.popup.toggle();
    }
    OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
};
marker1.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);

var marker2 = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat2);
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);



var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(markers, lonLat2);

feature.closeBox = true;
feature.popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.AnchoredBubble, { autoSize: true });
feature.data.popupContentHTML = '<p>Marker2<p>';
feature.data.overflow = "hidden";
marker2.feature = feature;

var markerClick = function (evt) {
    if (this.popup == null) {
        this.popup = this.createPopup(this.closeBox);
        map.addPopup(this.popup);
        this.popup.show();
    } else {
        this.popup.toggle();
    }
    OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
};
marker2.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);



var marker3 = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat3);
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
    var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
    marker3.icon.size = size;
marker3.icon.offset = offset;
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(markers, lonLat3);
feature.closeBox = true;
feature.popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.AnchoredBubble, { autoSize: true });
feature.data.popupContentHTML = '<p>Marker 3<p>';
feature.data.overflow = "hidden";

marker3.feature = feature;

var markerClick = function (evt) {
    if (this.popup == null) {
        this.popup = this.createPopup(this.closeBox);
        map.addPopup(this.popup);
        this.popup.show();
    } else {
        this.popup.toggle();
    }
    OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
};
marker3.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);

markers.addMarker(marker1, icon1);

markers.addMarker(marker2, icon2);

markers.addMarker(marker3, icon3);

  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at Openlayers StyleMaps and lookup tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [OpenLayers Marker documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html) which has an example. You are passing the icon at the wrong location. It has to be done inside the `OpenLayers.Marker()` constructor and not at `OpenLayers.Layer.Markers.addMarker()`.

Instead of

```
var marker1 = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat1);
```

try

```
var marker1 = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat1, icon1);
```

and remove the second parameter at your `addMarker()` calls because they are ignored.